# verify state load page bootstrap switch

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap switch in my checkboxes. I want to check what is the state of my checkbox in loading the page using this library.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really difficult for us to debug a verbal description of your code. It would be much easier for us to help you if you provide us with the code that you have tried (even if it's not working). Please edit your question and add all the relevant code (don't put it in comments because the code formatting is awful). Then we can begin to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Look how simple it was to answer: D

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //get state
    var state = $("#checkbox").bootstrapSwitch('state');
});
```

Comment: This actually really helped me ! Thanks for posting your answer